# WPF how to update the View binded to ReadOnly property in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, readonly

I have WPF window Title-property binded to ViewModel ReadOnly property as:

```
Title="{Binding ClientAndDate}"
```

ViewModel property looks like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property ClientAndDate As String
    Get
       Return SelectedClient.Name) & " " & SelectedClient.Date)
    End Get
End Property
```

I have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented in ViewModel but since this is ReadOnly property how it will notify the UI to update when either SelectedClient.Name or SelectedClient.Date is changed?

Comment: I don't think that readonly will effect the `INotifyPropertyChanged` behavior? Are you facing any issue?

Comment: Yes but he must informate UI abaout change. i.e. he have to call changet event.

Answer (score 3):

If you subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of `SelectedClient`, you could then raise the property change event in the viewmodel on the `ClientAndDate` property whenever `Name` or `Date` are the cause of the property change from `SelectedClient`.

Even though the `ClientAndDate` property is read only, raising a property change notification for it anywhere in your viewmodel will cause the binding subsystem to refresh itself from the property.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was using already. Just thought this is not the best practice since it can become pretty messy code to manage when there are lots of those read-only properties. Researched also this elsewhere and seems there are really no fully elegant solutions to this.

Answer (score -1):

You have to make some "notify" method.

Like this one.

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
     PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
     if (handler != null)
     {
         handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
     }
}
```

And call it with "ClientAndDate" argument every tyme you need update UI.

"ClientAndDate" is name of property that was updated.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) is whole example with GET statement but you can use it same way.

Comment: Ôo I don't understand it. How should this method be useful, if it's implemented in a view class?

Comment: Then your first sentence is misleading  *You have to make some "notify" method in your page/window class.* I didn't follow your link.

Comment: No. Is this method is propertyChanged event called.

`handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));`

Comment: I know what the rest of your post is meaning. But the first sentence is still misleading, since you're talking of a *page/window class*. You must only rephrase it and everything will be fine... ;o)

Comment: Oh. Yes. You are right. I forget that he want this in ViewModel. Sorry ;D